# How to train a neural network LSTM with MFCC coefficients in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, conv-neural-network, speech-recognition, mfcc

I am currently trying to train a neural network with MFCC. I have obtained a function where I've come up with 12 coefficients for each frame the audio was divided. The MFCC is of the Format 13*7586 double. My question is how can I train a network with MFCC coefficients. And what about the data labelling?

[image: mfcc1]

[image: mfcc2]